# public holiday in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
function myFunction(){
    var today = new Date();
    var month = today.getMonth()+1;
    var date = today.getDate();
    
    if (month=== 1 && date===1){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 1 && date===2){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month===1 && date===9){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 2 && date===11){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 2 && date===23){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 3 && date===21){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 4 && date===29){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 5 && date===3){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month===5 && date===4){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 5 && date===5){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 7 && date===17){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 8 && date===11){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 9 && date===18){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 9 && date===23){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 10 && date===9){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 11 && date===3){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    }
    if (month=== 11 && date===23){
      window.location = "http://google.com";
    } else{
      window.location = "http://10.2.3.30:81";
  }
}
```

so basically i have tried to incorporate javascript in my simple practice html file where by when i press a button the program should verify where it matches with the dates(public holidays) given and if it does it should redirect to another website or else it should be able to access the server. But the problem is that if any of the dates fall on a weekend then the holiday is carried over to a the staring of the new week day. And also i want to know how to get date and month from the internet rather than the date of the device the html runs on. Please help(beginner here)

Comment: date may differ according to the time zones , specify any?

Comment: time zone is tokyo japan.

Comment: Your code won't work as it's written at the moment... This should be a chain of `else if` statements (actually this isn't a great way to do this, at all, but anyway). At the moment, `window.location = "http://10.2.3.30:81";` will run everyday, except for *November 23rd*... Do you see what I mean?

Comment: any suggestion on how i can make it better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use API http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Tokyo  for getting the datetime for Tokyo by ajax calling.

url1 : http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone
gives all the timezones with city/country names

url2 : http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Tokyo
gives the datetime for tokyo
with the following detais

```
{"abbreviation":"JST",
"client_ip":"117.245.152.80",
"datetime":"2022-08-09T16:14:30.067969+09:00",
"day_of_week":2,
"day_of_year":221,
"dst":false,
"dst_from":null,
"dst_offset":0,
"dst_until":null,
"raw_offset":32400,
"timezone":"Asia/Tokyo",
"unixtime":1660029270,
"utc_datetime":"2022-08-09T07:14:30.067969+00:00",
"utc_offset":"+09:00","week_number":32
}
```

```
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Tokyo',
        success: function (result) {
            var today = new Date(result.datetime); 
            console.log(today);
            myFunction(today);
        }
    });
});

function myFunction(idate){
    var today = new Date(idate);
......
}
```

After getting the datetime pass it to the function you coded and assign to the variable you created, the remaing it will take care.

Comment: just one more question where do i put the api code in ?

Comment: include jquery script in the head tag and place the api click function before myFunciton

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your code, and having multiple `if` statements like this is a code smell, and should be avoided at all costs.

As mentioned in my comment, you'll also always enter the `else` statement unless it's the date mentioned in the `if` statement preceding it.

```
function isPublicHoliday(){
  const today = new Date();
  const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
  const date = today.getDate();
  const holidays = [
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 9],
    [2, 11],
    [2, 23],
    [3, 21],
    [4, 29],
    [5, 3],
    [5, 4],
    [5, 5],
    [7, 17],
    [8, 11],
    [9, 18],
    [9, 23],
    [10, 9],
    [11, 3],
    [11, 23]
  ];

  for (const holiday of holidays) {
    if (month === holiday[0] && date === holiday[1]) {
      window.location = "http://google.com";
      return;
    }
  }

  window.location = "http://10.2.3.30:81";
}
```

Is a lot neater, doesn't have the bug in it, and is much more maintainable. If a public holiday is added, or removed, you just remove its entry from the array. You can also do this programmatically in the future, by adding hooks, or taking arguments in the function, but that's outside the scope of the question.

Oh, and name your functions properly, even when prototyping, it's just a good habit to get in to.

TBH, you also probably want to stick to using functions to do one thing, so in this case, you want to check if *today is a public holiday*. Which is a yes or no question. As such you want to get a yes or no response. Something like:

```
// Do stuff...
const todayIsAHoliday = isPublicHoliday();
if (todayIsAHoliday) {
  window.location = "http://google.com";
} else {
  window.location = "http://10.2.3.30:81";
}
// Do more stuff...

// Functions declared with this syntax will be `hoisted` when
// the JavaScript is run, so it's fine to have it defined at the
// bottom of your script.
function isPublicHoliday(){
  const today = new Date();
  const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
  const date = today.getDate();
  const holidays = [
    [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 9], [2, 11],
    [2, 23], [3, 21], [4, 29], [5, 3],
    [5, 4], [5, 5], [7, 17], [8, 11],
    [9, 18], [9, 23], [10, 9], [11, 3],
    [11, 23]
  ];

  for (const holiday of holidays) {
    if (month === holiday[0] && date === holiday[1]) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

You can even implement some re-usability for your function, which is also always good to try and do, and allow for an argument containing the public holidays, so it can easily be modified at a later date.

Building on the previous example, that leads us to:

```
// Do stuff...
const currentHolidays = [
  [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 9], [2, 11],
  [2, 23], [3, 21], [4, 29], [5, 3],
  [5, 4], [5, 5], [7, 17], [8, 11],
  [9, 18], [9, 23], [10, 9], [11, 3],
  [11, 23]
];
const todayIsAHoliday = isPublicHoliday(currentHolidays);
if (todayIsAHoliday) {
  window.location = "http://google.com";
} else {
  window.location = "http://10.2.3.30:81";
}
// Do more stuff...

// We can give the argument a default value, for how the public
// holidays stand at the moment, but with an option to override
// them in the future.
function isPublicHoliday(holidays = [
    [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 9], [2, 11],
    [2, 23], [3, 21], [4, 29], [5, 3],
    [5, 4], [5, 5], [7, 17], [8, 11],
    [9, 18], [9, 23], [10, 9], [11, 3],
    [11, 23]
  ]) {
  const today = new Date();
  const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
  const date = today.getDate();

  for (const holiday of holidays) {
    if (month === holiday[0] && date === holiday[1]) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

There are other things I could mention, but that should give you a bit of insight in to things to think about in general when working with JavaScript.

Comment: I am sorry to be asking too many questions but is there anyway i can add more conditions to the program such that if it does fall on a weekend it automatically considers the starting day of the next week as a holiday?

Comment: You can... But that does complicate matters somewhat... Dates are awkward to work with when it comes to calendars, as the number of days in a year aren't even constant! You're better off working with a library for this kind of thing, where groups of people have already worked out the nitty gritty of the algorithm, or an API. A quick Google search turned up [this](https://holidayapi.com/countries/jp/2022), which seems to offer everything you want.

Comment: Mr. Jack could you help me figure out how to use the API for current time so that the date and time of the device uses doesn't matter. Please